# How to configure NserviceBus with AzureStorageQueueTransport and Azure Storage account which is having private access level

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4, nservicebus5, nservicebus3, nservicebus-distributor

We are using NserviceBus with AzureStorageQueueTransport & storage account with public access but now we have to use Azure Storage account which is having private access level.

1. Is there any way to create a SAS token and append while creating endpoint and send , publish ,receive messages.
2. Is there any support from NServiceBus for this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> We are using NserviceBus with AzureStorageQueueTransport & storage account with public access but now we have to use Azure Storage account which is having private access level.

It's not clear what do you mean by "public access". You should be using the transport with a [connection string](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-storage-queues/configuration#connection-strings) that contains the account name and the key, which should **not** be public.

> Is there any way to create a SAS token and append while creating endpoint and send , publish ,receive messages.

The transport is currently is expecting a connection string and will not work with a URI that contains a service SAS token. You can raise a request if you need that functionality.